# How can my wife and I share our iCal calendars on my home wireless network?

Tags: macos, mac, sync, calendar, calendar.app

I'm looking for an easy way to share iCal calendars that my wife and I have setup for ourselves on separate computers with each other. I'd like to do it without having to setup a calendar server or web server for that purpose and without signing up with MobileMe.

Update 1: I've discovered I have some additional requirements. I'd like to maintain separate calendars for my kids that my wife and I can both edit. Also, the email address for my domain name is a Google Apps domain and so is my wife's but her's is a different domain. If we both had email addresses using the same domain name it would work a little better with Google Apps but I was going to just create a dummy email address on my domain for her calendar.

Update 2: I've discovered that using the Microsoft Exchange protocol on Google Apps (sync) works well to keep separate Calendars for my myself and kids and keeps them in sync on my iPhone.

Update 3: If you use Microsoft Exchange protocol to sync Google calendars with the iPhone, those calendars need to be created on Google and not the iPhone or iCal.

Comment: Instead of using ActiveSync you can use CalDAV with Google's Calendar to sync with iCal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Google Calendar as my "storage", then sync to iCal and our iPhones using the built in methods.

This has the advantage that I can't physically lose the iCal file, and means that I can access it on any computer if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use '[BusySync](http://www.busymac.com/busysync/index.html)' to do across-the-LAN synchronisation, without involving Google (though it can also sync with there too.)